# Getting different results when converting timestamp to text

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, psql

I'm tying to convert timestamp field in format (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.MS`) to it's text representation. But for some reason getting different results:

If I'm trying to convert timestamp from table:

```
create table test_dt (dt timestamp);
insert into test_dt values ('2016-04-14 17:10:33.007');
insert into test_dt values ('2016-04-14 17:10:33');
```

Timestamps are getting truncated up to the seconds:

```
select dt::text from test_dt;
         dt          
---------------------
 2016-04-14 17:10:33
 2016-04-14 17:10:33
(2 rows)
```

But if Im using direct select statement, everything works:

```
select '2016-04-14 17:10:33.007'::timestamp::text;
         varchar         
-------------------------
 2016-04-14 17:10:33.007
(1 row)
```

The question is not how to convert it to the text from table and include precision, but rather:

- what am I doing wrong?
- why those 2 approaches returns different result?
- what's the rational behind this behaviour?

#### UPDATE

as @muistooshort suggested the following command gives the correct result:

```
select c::text from (select '2016-04-14 17:10:33.007'::timestamp union select '2016-04-14 17:10:33'::timestamp ) as t(c);
            c            
-------------------------
 2016-04-14 17:10:33
 2016-04-14 17:10:33.007
(2 rows)
```

and yes `test_dt` does have `.007` :

```
select * from test_dt;
           dt            
-------------------------
 2016-04-14 17:10:33
 2016-04-14 17:10:33.007
(2 rows)
```

Also `to_char` gives milliseconds from the table:

```
select to_char(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.MS') from test_dt;
         to_char         
-------------------------
 2016-04-14 05:10:33.000
 2016-04-14 05:10:33.007
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) to convert date and time types to `text` rather than a type cast? `to_char` gives you control over the formatting/conversion at least. PS: "rational" versus "rationale", you want the latter here.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for pointing to `to_char` function. Im aware of that, but was wondering more about not how to convert it, but rather what are the differences between 2 approaches. And why 1 is showing correct result  but not the other.

Comment: Doesn't happen for me in PostgreSQL 9.4, must be a RedShift-ism. Does it show the truncation with `select c::text from (values ('2016-04-14 17:10:33.007'::timestamp),('2016-04-14 17:10:33'::timestamp)) as t(c)`? I'm assuming that you've checked `select dt from test_dt` to make sure you really do have the `.007` in the table.

Comment: @muistooshort  Ive slightly modified the syntax of your expression to be "redshift" compatable and got correct result. Does it give you any clue what might be wrong?
P.S and yes `test_dt` has `.007` in the table.

Comment: The only clue I have here is that RedShift is based on a truly ancient version of PostgreSQL (8.0), maybe the casting behavior has changed over the years.